# Delphi XE10.2 Form not nil after Release

Tags: forms, delphi

A technique I used for years in Delphi is no longer working, because a form I'm creating is not set to nil after it's released. Here's some sample code:

```
type 
  TAboutForm = class(TForm);
  end;

function ShowAboutForm: TModalResult;
function ShowAboutForm2: TModalResult;

implementation

var
  FAboutForm: TAboutForm;

{$R *.dfm}

function AboutForm: TAboutForm;
begin
  if not Assigned(FAboutForm) then
    FAboutForm := TAboutForm.Create(Application);
  Result := FAboutForm;
end;

function ShowAboutForm: TModalResult;
begin
  with AboutForm do
    try
      Result := ShowModal;
    finally
      Release;
    end;
end;

function ShowAboutForm2: TModalResult;
var
  AAboutForm: TAboutForm;
begin
  AAboutForm := AboutForm;
    try
      Result := AAboutForm.ShowModal;
    finally
      AAboutForm.Release;
      AABoutForm := nil;
    end;
end;
```

Neither ShowAboutForm nor ShowAboutForm2 works the second time around. Both throw Access Violations, because FAboutForm is not set to nil by either method -- even though ShowAboutForm2 explicitly sets the local variable to nil -- so it's not being re-created in AboutForm. The only way I've found to get the code to work is this:

```
function ShowAboutForm3: TModalResult;
begin
  fAboutForm := AboutForm;
  try
    Result := fAboutForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    fAboutForm.Release;
    fAboutForm := nil;
  end;
```

Is this an appropriate way to deal with creating and releasing forms? Why isn't the form being freed unless I reference the implemented var directly?

Comment: That technique never worked properly. You got lucky and never had a problem. Read the documentation for Release. It does not do what you think it does. If you want the form freed, then call Free - it does *exactly* what it's name says it does.

Comment: I find this a little surprising. You didn't set the variable to nil so why would you expect it to be nil? I think underlying this you don't fully understand how pointers and references work and that you should concentrate on getting that sorted so it is clear in your mind.

Answer (score 9):

Your technique has always been broken. If it ever worked it was merely by chance.

In the first example, where you are just releasing the form, you never set its global reference to `nil`, so it will point to invalid memory where your form object instance used to reside.

In the second example you are setting the local reference to your form object to `nil`, and not the global one you test later on. Since the reference you are testing with `Assigned` was never set to `nil`, it also points to invalid memory.

A variable (reference) represents only a pointer to the memory where the real object is located. You can have multiple pointers to the same object instance. But each and every one of those references is independent. If you set one to `nil`, or to any other value, the other references will still point to whatever they were pointing before.

The real solution, as you have already discovered, is to set the `fAboutForm` reference to `nil`, since this is the one you are testing with `Assigned`.

---

Also, since you are using the global variable to keep the reference and you assign that variable in the `AboutForm` function, you don't actually have to assign it again in `ShowAboutForm3` with `fAboutForm := AboutForm`.

It does not have any influence on your code functionality, it will work just the same, but it is a bit messy.

Comment: FWIW "3" is also broken, a procedure cannot return a result.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz good point, but it falls to the typo category, not relevant to the real question.